# How to perform string contains check in handlebarsjs

Tags: handlebars.js

How to perform string contains check in handlebarsjs within the if block

```
\{{ if loop_var.imageUri }}
  
      # if loop_var.imageUri contains foo
        <img width="50" height="50" src="{{loop_var.imageUri}}"/>
      # else
        <img width="150" height="150" src="{{loop_var.imageUri}}"/>
      # end

\{{ else }}

\{{ end }}
```

Comment: You would need to create a custom helper. See: https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#basic-blocks

Answer (score 1):

Handlebars has no helper to do a contains comparison on two strings, but you can easily create your own. It would need to be a [Block Helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/block-helpers.html#block-helpers) so that you can add the `{{else}}` branch for cases of non-matches.

```js
const template = Handlebars.compile(`
{{#if loop_var.imageUri}}
  {{#ifContains loop_var.imageUri 'foo'}}
    <img width="50" height="50" src="{{loop_var.imageUri}}"/>
  {{else}}
    <img width="150" height="150" src="{{loop_var.imageUri}}"/>
  {{/ifContains}}
{{/if}}
`);

Handlebars.registerHelper('ifContains', function (source, subString, options) {
  if (source.indexOf(subString) > -1) {
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
  }
});

const data = {
  loop_var: {
    imageUri: '/my/foo/image/'
  }
};

const output = template(data);

document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.7.7/handlebars.min.js"></script>
```